# Flexbox not aligned

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to create 6 boxes in the middle and display some features inside.

I am using `display: inline-flex` but for I can't get them to align properly, the last box seems out of the place. 
I don't want to use Bootstrap or any other framework but make this with pure CSS.

I am expecting to have aligned 6 boxes in the middle of centered div. This is what I have tried, example of snippet

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 80px;
}

.flexi {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.jebote {
  border: 3px solid green;

}
.jebote5 {
  border: 3px solid green;

}

.jebote6 {
  border: 3px solid green;

}
.h1 {
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<div class="flexi">
  <div class="inline">
    <div class="jebote">
    <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/></a>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
    <p style="font-size:14px;">
      Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when it
      comes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out in
      competitive market.
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexi">
    <div class="inline">
      <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/></a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px; ">Consulting and Strategy</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px">
        To develop efficient software and reduce the related costs, process
        and technology consulting are essential and integral part of every
        business strategy.
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexi">
    <div class="inline">
      <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/></a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Design and Creative Work</p>
      <p style="font-size: 14px;">
        Design plays a key role in engaging visitors and converting them
        into customers. We focus on creating memorable interactions through
        our designs.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Bottom row cards-->

<div class="flexi">
  <div class="inline">
    <div class="jebote">
    <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/></a>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Mobile Applications</p>
    <p style="font-size:14px;">
      We like to think of the problem the app intends to solve, analyze
      mobility context and create a mobile solution meeting that need and
      satisfying user experience.
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="flexi">
    <div class="inline">
      <div class="jebote5">
      <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/></a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Website Development</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px">
        Professional, responsive, engaging and value driven web sites are
        true support to every business. They help engage the customers and
        gain an edge over the competitors.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="flexi">
    <div class="inline">
      <div class="jebote6">
      <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/></a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">E-Commerce Development</p>
      <p style="font-size: 14px;">
        Building intuitive, useful, secure and accessible e-Commerce
        solutions that power the transactions and digital experience is
        important to us..
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why do you have `flexi` as parent row and then 3 children ( cols ) with classes `inline, flexi, flexi` ? shouldn't the row have `flexi` and the children to all have `inline` class? Maybe ? And there are a bunch of ' strange ' things in your HTML structure. I suggest you clean-up your HTML and make one where you have a class for the row, a class for the columns and a class for the children of the columns. Do not use same classes for parents and for children

Comment: I did that in order to make the bottom row flexed alligned, removing flexi and leaving only 1 parents makes the bottom row a listed and not in a block

Comment: your structure should look like `<div class="flexi"><div class="jebote"></div><div class="jebote"></div><div class="jebote"></div></div>` for one row. And replicate that row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution but using CSS Grid, the html was cleaned a bit.

The key part here is this line `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` it tells to the grid that we want 3 columns and each one should use the same space `1fr` (1 fraction of the available space)

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 80px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.flexi {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="center">

  <div class="flexi">
   <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png" /></a>
   <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
   <p style="font-size:14px;">
    Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when it
    comes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out in
    competitive market.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexi">
   <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png" /></a>
   <p style="font-size: 20px; ">Consulting and Strategy</p>
   <p style="font-size:14px">
    To develop efficient software and reduce the related costs, process
    and technology consulting are essential and integral part of every
    business strategy.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexi">
   <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png" /></a>
   <p style="font-size: 20px;">Design and Creative Work</p>
   <p style="font-size: 14px;">
    Design plays a key role in engaging visitors and converting them
    into customers. We focus on creating memorable interactions through
    our designs.
   </p>
  </div>

  <!--  Bottom row cards-->

  <div class="flexi">
   <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png" /></a>
   <p style="font-size: 20px;">Mobile Applications</p>
   <p style="font-size:14px;">
    We like to think of the problem the app intends to solve, analyze
    mobility context and create a mobile solution meeting that need and
    satisfying user experience.
   </p>
  </div>


   <div class="flexi">
    <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png" /></a>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Website Development</p>
    <p style="font-size:14px">
     Professional, responsive, engaging and value driven web sites are
     true support to every business. They help engage the customers and
     gain an edge over the competitors.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="flexi">
    <a href="#news"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png" /></a>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">E-Commerce Development</p>
    <p style="font-size: 14px;">
     Building intuitive, useful, secure and accessible e-Commerce
     solutions that power the transactions and digital experience is
     important to us..
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't wrap everything up in so much html tags if there is no need for it, keep it clean and readable.

Also, if you add a class "jebote" for a border, just create it once and add the class "jebote" to the elements you want to apply a border. again, this will keep it clean and readable.

Although my solution is below, i highly recommend you to read this guide:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```html
<style>
  .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 80px;
  }

  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
  }

  .jebote {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
</style>
<div class="center">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news">
        <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/>
      </a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when itcomes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out incompetitive market.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news">
        <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/>
      </a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when itcomes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out incompetitive market.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news">
        <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/>
      </a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when itcomes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out incompetitive market.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news">
        <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/>
      </a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when itcomes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out incompetitive market.</p>
    </div>  <div class="jebote">
    <a href="#news">
      <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/>
    </a>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
    <p style="font-size:14px;">Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when itcomes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out incompetitive market.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="jebote">
      <a href="#news">
        <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-green-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/40x40/theater%20symbol.png"/>
      </a>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;">Custome Software Solutions</p>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">Every business is unique and there is no “one-size-fits-all” when itcomes to technology solutions that drive growth and stand you out incompetitive market.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not true, did you try it and change the titles and/or the text? you'll see it works.